# I only get the first 7 href when i scrape linkedin job posting

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

this is the URL : https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3702922458

```
base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com'

page_source = driver.page_source

# Parse the HTML content with BeautifulSoup
soup = bs(page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find all the anchor tags containing job links
cells = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'full-width artdeco-entity-lockup__title ember-view'})
href = cell['href']

for link in cells:
    job_url = base_url + href
    print(job_url)
```

i used Chatgpt, but with no results at all

Comment: Why are you using BeautifulSoup instead of using the native Selenium APIs to search the DOM?  The `page_source` has what was originally delivered, and since this page is built dynamically with Javascript, it's not going to have everything.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to scrape job listings from LinkedIn using Selenium and BeautifulSoup.

Unfortunately, the provided code snippet contains several logical errors and is generally incorrect. It's challenging to address the issues individually.

I recommend rewriting the code from scratch. Focus on parsing the HTML correctly and iterating through the links accurately. Feel free to ask for assistance once you've revised the code.

Additionally, using BeautifulSoup is not necessary since Selenium already offers methods to query the DOM. This could help to avoid some issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
base_url = 'https://www.linkedin.com'

page_source = driver.page_source

# Parse the HTML content with BeautifulSoup
soup = bs(page_source, 'html.parser')

# Find all the anchor tags containing job links
cells = soup.find_all('div', class_='artdeco-entity-lockup__title')

for link in cells:
    key = link.attrs.keys()
    if 'href' in key:
        href = link.attrs['href']
        job_url = base_url + href
        print(job_url)
```